# Joining to index to make a single selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've written a selector used within python script which is able to grab the movie name from a webpage based on it's index. I just wish to get the name of two movies [I repeat, two movies] whether it is 1,2 or 3,4 or 15,16 whatever. Basically my intention is to join two index to make a individual selector? In this case I used two index 0 and 1 to make a single selector with "+" operhand to join it. I believe there should be any smarter way to do the same. To be more specific, see the below examples:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://yts.ag/browse-movies").text,'html.parser')
movie = soup.select(".browse-movie-title")[0].text + soup.select(".browse-movie-title")[1].text
print(movie)
```

This is the result:

It Comes at Night Mindhorn

EDIT:

For the clarity of what I've said below:

List like result:

```
['Mindhorn', 'Dead Again in Tombstone']
```

newline result:

```
Mindhorn
Dead Again in Tombstone
```

Expected output:

```
Mindhorn Dead Again in Tombstone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension you can get the title of the `n` first movies:

```py
movies = [m.text for m in soup.select(".browse-movie-title")][:n]
```

Then you can print the results into different lines if you wish:

```py
print('\n'.join(movies))
```

**Edit:** apparently BeautifulSoup doesn't support some CSS pseudo-classes like `nth-child`, otherwise you could limit the number of children nodes from the query. For the record, this selector works from the Chrome console:

```
section .row .browse-movie-wrap:nth-child(-n+2)
```

Comment: Thanks stjernaluiht, you are the gem. It is what I was expecting. Btw, could you suggest me how can I print the result neither in newline nor in list-like but what we see in general. Let me know if you don't understand what I meant.

Comment: I don't understand, any example?

Comment: Thanks for your response. See the edited part above.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. You need `print(' '.join(movies))`. Notice the single space before `.join`, this is how you define the separator between the elements.

Comment: I owe you bigtime. You are the genius. Thankssssssssssss a lot.